# Alternative to mailto: to link email

Tags: html, css, email

I am creating a website and there is a page with people that are part of the company. Each person has an email that i want for the user to be able to get the email for the person that he/she want.

If we were in 2011 i would have used mailto: html tag. But really not so many people are using desktop email clients.

I thought about linking to a link so a new window would open in gmail and a new message would be created with recepient the pressed email. BUT not everyone uses gmail.

The only posible "solution" that i though that when the user clicks on the email this would be copied automatically in the clipboard. It would have the same result as doing CTRL & C at something. BUT this requires a lot of time and i dont want to get my hands dirty with javascript.

Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: Is using a server side library out of the question? You could pop up a modal with a basic form and send it through something like postmarkapp. or just your own server's mail using PHP or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably still use mailto:. mailto: is not intended for just desktops, it identifies a handler for the client. A mobile device would be able to recognize it just as well, and launch its preferred MTU.

Answer (score 0):

With a lot of addons like [smartaddon contact form](https://web.archive.org/web/20181111004043/http://smartaddon.com:80/contact_form.html) and [foxyform](https://www.foxyform.com/) available out there, you could add them to your html code.

But, if you could use php, it to would just take few statements of code to set up the contact form on your own. Refer [this](https://tangledindesign.com/how-to-create-a-contact-form-using-html5-css3-and-php/) post which explains clearly on how to set up your contact form using php.